# EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

How does one resolve this Blazor Server error?

> EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext
> parameter

I have created a minimally reproducible example below. The issue seems to be because the model is not instantiated...Why does the following simple page throw this error?

```
@page "/"
<EditForm @Model="@person">
    <input @bind="@person.FirstName" />
    <input @bind="@person.LastName" />
</EditForm>
@code 
{
    public Person person = new Person();
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        person = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "Fred",
            LastName = "Flintstone"
        };
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not only tell you the error, but tell you how to check it while typing in VS.

Change to this:

```
<EditForm Model="@person">
```

**(i.e. with no "@" sign on `Model`)**

When you're typing in the `<Editform>` line, when you press space, you'll see the list of expected variables, several of which start with `@`, like `@ref`, and several which do not, like `Model`.

Comment: In newer versions of Blazor. You don't need the `"@ "` for the variable either. Like this: 
`<EditForm Model=person>
   ...
</EditForm>`.

This works with most custom Blazor Tags.

Comment: I had an answer to this question as well, but I deleted it yesterday. At the time of my original posting, I didn't have enough Rep to leave a comment. A few days ago, someone downvoted my answer and I thought it was due to me elaborating on your answer and not making it a comment instead. I noticed that I now have enough Rep to leave a comment. So I deleted my answer to this question and moved it to the comment section. I wonder if the same person who downvoted me downvoted your answer as well??? I can undelete my answer if you would like proof. I promise I don't want to ruffle any feathers

Comment: Stack Overflow says that I upvoted your answer on December 6th, 2023. I am not sure why it notified you that I downvoted instead of upvoting. Again, I am sorry for the confusion

Comment: It's all good.  Your comment was 100% valid, and could be useful as it is currently the preferred syntax.  My recommendation would be to cite a version when commenting very old threads: "Since  .Net 5, the preferred syntax is XYZ." or "As of today, in 2024, we can do XYZ."  Blazor's super-fast development cycle can make it hard to track which Blazor-verse you're talking about.

Comment: My preferred method now, BTW, is to skip EditForm unless I really want the built in verbose validation.  I normally just use vanilla html controls bound to parameters or variables in the `@code` section.  It's surprising how rarely I actually need to validate input, despite having maybe 100 components in my site.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! I'll certainly implement that going forward! Like you, I don't often use EditForm. I completely agree! I primarily stick to vanilla HTML with C# as well. Occasionally, if basic validation is needed, it's usually for just one or two properties, and implementing a simple custom validation is easier than bringing in the entire EditForm. However, the majority of my validation work is done on the back-end server since I am using front-end Blazor (WASM).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after adding an **EditForm** to **NavMenu.razor** in a .net 8 blazor ssr and I had to use EditContext and remove Model property from EditForm tag in NavMenu.razor only.

```
<EditForm OnSubmit="Submit" FormName="SearchForm" EditContext="editContext">
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="vm!.SearchText" class="form-control" placeholder />
        <label>Title</label>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

cs file :

```
[SupplyParameterFromForm] public SearchVm? vm { get; set; }
private EditContext? editContext;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    vm ??= new();
    editContext = new(vm);
}

public void Submit()
{
    if (vm!.SearchText!.IsEmpty() == false)
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"Search/{vm!.SearchText}");
}
```

IsEmpty() extension method :

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty(this string input)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.Trim());
    }
}
```